# Block Docker container ports with iptables/firewalld

Tags: docker, iptables, firewalld

I have an docker-compose deployment with a container, e.g.:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
```

Docker version is 20.10.9, OS is CentOS 7.

I need to block access to 8080 port from external IP addresses except specified.

But `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 --src ! <IP whitelist>  -j DROP` doesn't work for docker containers.

In a system with firewalld settings for `public` zone aren't applied for Docker containers.

DOCKER-USER chain doesn't work as needed because I should use `--dport 80` (internal port in docker container) not `dport 8080`. But I need to use external port because there can be many containers with internal port 80, but external port is unique.

I used

Answer (score 0):

When I want to block container ports I change the DOCKER-USER chain.

As far as I know: Traffic to docker never touches the INPUT chain in iptables.

So I would try:

```
iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i <INCOMING-INTERFACE> -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 --src ! <IP whitelist>  -j DROP
```

More infos: https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/